# Having Trouble while dealing with char in Binary Tree

Tags: c, char, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary tree that accepts character(first i tried with integer it worked so i am trying with character).Initially i tried with int data it worked fine so i changed that to char data and changed theformat specifiers accordingly..but now it is not taking input as before.Kindly help me in this
regard.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     int t=1;
     struct node
     {
         char data;
         struct node *left;
         struct node *right;
     };
    struct node* addnode()
    {
        struct node *p;
        char temp;
        if(t==1)
        {
          printf("Enter data\n");
          t=2;
        }
         scanf("%c",&temp);
         printf("If there is no data enter z\n");
         if(temp=='z')
         return NULL;
         p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         p->data=temp;
         printf("Enter left child of %c",temp);
         p->left=addnode();
         printf("Enter right child of %c",temp);
         p->right=addnode();
    }
    int main()
    {
        struct node *root;
        root=addnode();
    }
```

Comment: works fine. what is your issue?

Comment: I tried giving input as a b z z c z z 1 0 in this code https://onecompiler.com/c/3vvjbyh9r it is giving answer as infinite loop..

Comment: it works fine on my Mac with the same input. your one compiler site is probably buggy. try using real tools.